# DataSource: GDALException: Unknown error code: "-474873798"

Tags: django, geodjango

I find a strange thing:

after `python manage.py shell`, when I try to use GDAL interface to create a data source using `django.contrib.gis.gdal.DataSource` it will throws an error first and then the second try will succeed.

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource
shp = 'someshapefile.shp'
ds = DataSource(shp)
```

this will raise a `GDALException: : Unknown error code: "-474873798"` the code string varies from time to time.

but when try again: `ds = DataSource(shp)` the data source object is instantiated.

Similar problems also happen to `ogrinspect` command and loading data via `LayerMapping` object.

Here is the complete error prompt:

```
from django.contrib.gis.gdal import DataSource
shp = 'province.shp'
DataSource(shp)
GDALException                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c4eb8c662773> in <module>()
----> 1 DataSource(shp)

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py in __init__(self, ds_input, ds_driver, write, encoding)
     62         self.encoding = encoding
     63 
---> 64         Driver.ensure_registered()
     65 
     66         if isinstance(ds_input, six.string_types):

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py in ensure_registered(cls)
     81         if not cls.driver_count():
     82             vcapi.register_all()
---> 83             rcapi.register_all()
     84 
     85     @classmethod

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/errcheck.py in check_errcode(result, func, cargs, cpl)
    117     Check the error code returned (c_int).
    118     """
--> 119     check_err(result, cpl=cpl)
    120 
    121 

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/error.py in check_err(code, cpl)
     72         raise e(msg)
     73     else:
---> 74         raise GDALException('Unknown error code: "%s"' % code)

GDALException: Unknown error code: "-474873798"

DataSource(shp)
<django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource.DataSource at 0x10cd6f4a8>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can replicate this behaviour trying to import a gpx. Calling datasource = DataSource(gpx) twice instantiates the DataSource.

My hopefully temporary solution is to do this in my app:

```
try:
    datasource = DataSource(gpx)
except:
    datasource = DataSource(gpx)
```

I [filed a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27960) for Django.

Due to which my issue now has been fixed. See [ticket comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27960#comment:9).